# Reorder datatable column by Column Name using c#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have 1 datatable ,I want reOrder all datacolumn position based on the Column name .

Suppose i have datatable like this

```
  Click    Impression   Cost   Click-past  Impression-past   cost-past 
     1          2          3       11           22               33
```

then How to order given column to get data like it

```
  Click    Click-past  Impression   Impression-past   Cost   cost-past
    1           11        2                22           3        33
```

I am using **SetOrdinal**  but not able to make logic to get above output

Comment: could you add your code?

Comment: What is the "Previous-" in the edit? That doesn't exist in the "datatable like this". What is the logic behind the "sort" here? `SetOrdinal` works just fine...

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in functionto do this, I think.

I would put all column names in a List, sort this and copy all columns to a new table, where you can create the columns in the right order.

SetOrdinal is a pain, because it shift's the Index of all other columns too.

No code given since there is no code in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty, but it works:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable {
    Columns = {
        "Click", "Impression", "Cost", "Click-past",
        "Impression-past", "cost-past"
    }
};
Dictionary<string, DataColumn> colByName = dt.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>()
    .ToDictionary(x => x.ColumnName, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
List<DataColumn> sorted = new List<DataColumn>(dt.Columns.Count);
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
    if (!col.ColumnName.EndsWith("-past",
        StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        sorted.Add(col);
        DataColumn past;
        if (colByName.TryGetValue(col.ColumnName + "-past", out past))
            sorted.Add(past);
    }
}
int ordinal = 0;
foreach(var col in sorted)
{
    col.SetOrdinal(ordinal++);
}
foreach(DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    System.Console.WriteLine(col.ColumnName);
```

Note that any unaccounted-for `-past` columns (without a non-past twin) will automatically be shunted to the right, preserving their original order.

Answer (score 0):

```
 DataTable dt_reorder = ds1.Tables[i];

                //string[] columnNames = (from dc in dt_reorder.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>() select dc.ColumnName).OrderByDescending(c => c.Colum);

                System.Collections.Generic.List<string> lstColNames = (from DataColumn col in dt_reorder.Columns select col.ColumnName).ToList();



                foreach (string value in lstColNames)
                {
                    string aa = value.ToString();
                    if (!aa.Contains("-past"))
                    {
                        if (lstColNames.Contains(aa + "-past"))
                        {
                            dt_reorder.Columns[aa + "-Previous"].SetOrdinal(dt_reorder.Columns.IndexOf(aa) + 1);
                        }

                    }

                }
```